# how to make image in over than other like this

Tags: html, css, image

I have a random file name like this:

```
iw5_x1_mp_x2_x3_x4_x5_x6
```

and the "x" values are the random texts. like this:

```
iw5_mp9_mp_aco_silence_texture1
```

and i have image for all this random texts like this:

iw5_x1_mp.jpg, aco.jpg, silence.jpg, texture1.jpg

every thing i need to show this images with like this preview:

```
 _______________________________________________
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                iw5_x1_mp.jpg                  |
|                                               |
| [x2.jpg] [x3.jpg] [x4.jpg] [x5.jpg] [x6.jpg]  |
|_______________________________________________|
```

The whole box is the "iw5_x1_mp.jpg" image and [x2.jpg] [x3.jpg] [x4.jpg] [x5.jpg] [x6.jpg] on over the iw5_x1_mp.jpg

how i can make like with html and css ?!

Comment: you want it to look like the above example? or with the images showing?

Comment: Have a look at the **CSS properties** `z-index` and `position: absolute`, `position: relative`

Comment: with the images showing (like above style)

Comment: from what @pbaldauf is saying is the iw5_x1_mp.jpg gonna be a background with the other images on top?

Comment: yes i want  iw5_x1_mp.jpg be a background with the other images on top

Comment: ok give me a minute and i will answer the question for you

Comment: I think this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0nkyorc4/) does basically what you want. The fine-tuning is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/mewuk/1/watch?html,css,output

```
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/32/thumbnail.png"></div>
          <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/32/thumbnail.png"></div>
          <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/32/thumbnail.png"></div>
          <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/32/thumbnail.png"></div>
          <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/32/thumbnail.png"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>


.container{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:290px;
  background:url(http://vecto2000.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Dark_Metal_Background.jpg) center top fixed;
  background:cover;
 }
.wrapper {
   max-width:180px;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:0 auto;
}
.thumbnail {
   display:inline; 
}
```

http://jsbin.com/mewuk/1/watch?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Based on your illustration : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5dj1kqt/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="back">
    <div class="icons">
        <img class="icon" src="http://wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_kitten_cute_foot_face_1504_256x256.jpg" alt="" />
        <img class="icon" src="http://wallpaperscraft.com/image/78458/256x256.jpg" alt="" />
        <img class="icon" src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9gus8QYjY1rw0ggfo3_r5_400.gif" alt="" />
        <img class="icon" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0WfeXbfYPESZcDc7JYgJPM77WWMyA9Wot_ZxqY2bLi2reWMHylNw3plNg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.back
{
    background-image: url("http://www.bideawee.org/Media/Image/Brafton/It-s-kitten-season--Is-your-home-ready-for-the-arrival-of-your-new-pet-_16001188_800827146_0_0_14067751_500.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    position: relative;
}

div.back .icons
{
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

div.back .icons img.icon
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0  0 4% 4%;
    width: 20%;
}
```